# changes to xamarin mainpage are not effective on next run

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have created a Cross platform application to create an android application. In Main page I have a toolbar and listview that lists the data from sqlite database. it was working all well and now when I am trying to do change to the same screen to add some more controls, its not working when I run the project to debug. New controls are not visible on the screen. Its always showing the old screen as it is.

Comment: I think I ran into this issue as well. I take it you've closed VS and killed all the processes and tried again? I think that may have been what resolved it for me

Comment: Then again, I also ran into an issue with Xamarin where I couldn't build, etc. I have a question on here about it. Ended up creating a new project and copy pasting code and it worked just fine.

Comment: Sometimes delete the obj and bin folders can help. Or change the configuration profile (from "Debug" to "Release" for example). It seems to be cached junk files

Answer (score 0):

i don't have the rep to comment, but I've found that kind of scenario often with Android.

Changing UI components don't update.

When I do UI changes I'll often uninstall the app off the Android first, as the most reliable way, as I'm sure I've done the "clean solution", delete bin/obj folders and still had issues with the app on the droid not being fully updated to the new UI.